# How to save a html5 page offline using manifest

Tags: html, manifest

I am trying to store a page offline using html5 manifest: My html=> test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" manifest="test.appcache">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello
<img src="includes/images/about.png" width="119" height="119">
</body>
</html>
```

My manifest file=> I have created a text file in dreamweaver and then changed the file and extension to test.appcache =>

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
test.html
/includes/images/about.png
```

This is still not working when iu test the page offline... Any ideas where I am going wrong?... regards J

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this in IE? IE does not support HTML5 offline capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

1.Manifest must be served with the mime-type "text/cache-manifest".so what you shall do first is to set mime-type.

For example, in Apache, add this line to your config file(.htaccess):

AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache

2.Test your page using google chrome.Check whether manifest works using chrome's console panel or type "chrome://appcache-internals/" in the url bar

PS.

### a page using manifest works like this:

1.first-ever,your page(1.html) is downloaded and showed

2.later,you change the content of 1.html,and update the manifest file,then you refresh the browser.

3.The browser first show 1.html using cached page,and then download changed 1.html as new cached source,then replace the old one.(before download,browser will check whether manifest is updated)

4.at this point,the browser hasn already showed the "1.html" page.so what you see is still the old page.

5.You refresh browser again.this time,browser will show 1.html using the new cached page,then you'll see the changed 1.html